# Image plane, camera location and real distance

Tags: rendering, camera, image

Suppose I have a situation as shown in the image bellow. A 3D-Object I want to project into a 2D-Image with respect to the real distance. But I don't really understand the connection between the distance to the "camera location" (on the right) and the distance to the image plane.

How do I have to choose the distance between the camera location and the image plane to get a result I would expect in reality?

[image]